# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, ioerror

I'm trying to add some informations of all the torrents file in a path to a Table of my MySQL database but it seems like i have some PATH problems.
As you can see there is the full path and it even detect the "charlie.torrent" so i don't really understand what is the problem.

*This is my code:*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import mysql.connector
import bencode
import binascii
import hashlib
import os
import sys

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="root", database="TORRENTS")
cursor = conn.cursor
path = "/home/florian/TorrentFiles"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
for file in dirs:
        try:
                with open(file, 'rb') as torrentfile:
                        torrent = bencode.bdecode(torrentfile.read())
                        user = ("torrent['info']['name']","torrent['info']['length'],'bytes'","(hashlib.sha1(bencode.bencode(torrent['info'])).hexdigest())")
                        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO torrent_infos (Name, Size, Hash) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)""", user)
        except bencode.BTL.BTFailure:
                continue


conn.close()
```

And i really don't understand the following output of my script:

```
root@debian:/home/florian/Documents/mysite/polls# python bdd.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bdd.py", line 17, in <module>
    with open(file, 'rb') as torrentfile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'charlie.torrent'
```

*I already had a look to the others same subjects without any result.*

Comment: you need `with open(path + file, 'rb') as torrentfile:`

Comment: @heinst, keep in mind that `path + file` is a simple concatenation.  If the path is `/home/user/torrents` then `path + file` gives you `/home/user/torrentscharlie.torrent`.  It's also relatively platform-specific, so you would have to modify the code for Unix-style paths vs Windows-style paths.  This is where `os.path.join` comes in as it will account for proper path separators (though it won't modify `path` itself).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to open a file located in `path`, but not including that path, which tries to open the file in the current working path of your Python script.  For example, if you run the script from `/home/user/script.py`, while your torrents are in `/home/user/torrents`.  When you do `open(file, 'rb')` you are doing `/home/user/charlie.torrent` as opposed to `/home/user/torrents/charlie.torrent`.  Try replacing `with open(file, 'rb')` with `with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'rb')`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the directory you are currently in to path.

```
...
dirs = os.listdir(path)
os.chdir(path)
for file in dirs:
...
```

That should work also.